# Kubernetes java admission controller

Tags: java, kubernetes

Is it possible to create webhook server for kubernetes admission controller using java. That is webhook server will be a java rest api endpoint which will be called from ValidatingWebhook Configuration.
Please let me know if there is any sample/example based on java which I refer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please check this test for `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration` and see if it helps: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-tests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/mock/V1ValidatingWebhookConfigurationTest.java#L133 ?

Comment: Hi Rohan,
  Thanks for sharing the link. It didn't give much insight. Basically what i am looking for is when I write a webhook server in java, then what kind of json response is expected by the kube-api-server. If any working example was there then it would have been very helpful.

Comment: ohk, Do you want to do the same things as done in this blog but in java : https://docs.giantswarm.io/advanced/custom-admission-controller/ ? If yes, I'll try to port this to java whenever I get time later today.

Comment: I think you would need to return `AdmissionResponse` based on the validation you do on the object provided in request body

Comment: I found this link helpful, Thanks soukron
https://github.com/soukron/openshift-admission-webhooks

Comment: Above link is in Javascript not Java. Do you have any plans to write a blogpost about this? I was trying to port this but somehow ValidatingWebhookConfiguration weren't working in my case

Answer (score 0):

It is in early phases but this a microframework for writing admission controllers in java, but already nicely usable.

https://github.com/java-operator-sdk/admission-controller-framework

But should be fairly simply from scratch using fabrci8 client as mentione in comments.